# Call command in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, call

I have a script that adds exceptions to the Java_Exception and it works.
The issue is after the script runs, I need it to call another script to run and no matter where I put the command in, It doesnt work.

I am hoping someone can tell me how to modify it so it works.
I have tried these forums, google and friends.

```
echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM SET EX_PATH="%APPDATA%\sun\Java\Deployment\Security\exception.sites"

SET EX_PATH="%APPDATA%\..\LocalLow\sun\Java\Deployment\Security\exception.sites"



REM Here list the site to register up
 
SET EX_SITE[0]=http://XXXXXX.XXXXXX.com

SET EX_SITE[1]=http://XXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com:8080



REM ↓ end index is aligned with the registration number of
 
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,1) DO (

    FINDSTR !EX_SITE[%%i]! %EX_PATH%

  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO !EX_SITE[%%i]!>> %EX_PATH% 
   

)
 
  Call %CD%Davids_Script\Inc\NEW_User.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because %cd% does not end with a `\`.  You need to change the call to

```
call %cd%\Davids_Script\Inc\NEW_User.bat
```

Comment: I found the answer. The %CD% was assigned where the bat was. In this case it was in the d:\David_Script\INC folder. So I changed it to %CD%New_User.bat and it worked.   Thank you for the help